# POI: Format integer in Excelsheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a List of integers, that i want to export to Excel. But everytime the value is shown  with decimal positions:

```
worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).setCellValue(2); // Excel shows here 2.00
```

After that I've tried it with an custom style:

```
CellStyle numericStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
numericStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#"));
worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(2));
worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).setCellStyle(numericStyle);
```

Now it seem to be correct formated in Excel, but Excel (2013) says, the file is unsafe and should not be edited.

How is the correct way to format an integer-cell with poi?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
numericStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0"));
```

where workbook is your HSSFWorkbook

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
// at the beggining, create one style that would be applied for all Integers
CellStyle integerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
integerStyle.setDataFormat(0);

// use style wherever you need it
worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).setCellValue(Integer.valueOf(2));
worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).setCellStyle(integerStyle);
```